# Webservice import

Tags: integration, webservices

I want to keep my Salesforce and other system in sync. Whenever data is inserted in the other system it should also be inserted in Salesforce. The data inserted can be large voulume of data. What approach and points should I take into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options that you can integrate your salesforce and external system:

1. **Using SOAP Apex Webervice Methods:**

Apex class methods can be exposed as custom SOAP Web service calls. This allows an external application to invoke an Apex Web service to perform an action in Salesforce. Download the WSDL and expose it to the external systems.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services.htm

2. **Building a Custom REST API in salesforce using APEX REST:**

You can build a custom HTTP API url in salesforce using the apex @RestResource annotation. You can expose this url to other system and ask them to POST a JSON to your URL every time a record inserted you can parse the JSON and map it to the fields for the record creation.

[rest API for Querying on Account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88715/rest-api-for-querying-on-account/88726#88726)

From above 2 options I strongly suggest to go with Custom REST API which is easy to build and execute due to the limitations on WSDL in salesforce and the consumption of these WSDL by the external systems.

**SOAP API using Java and c# Example:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm