# Is there a way to post Webhook notification data to Salesforce

Tags: apex, integration, webservices

Is there a way to post Webhook notification data to Salesforce? If not, and I must post notification data to my own server, how can Salesforce retrieve the data from my server?

Is there a workaround where I don't have to use my own server as a middleman?

Thank you,
AB

Comment: video on [salesforce webhook patterns](https://vimeo.com/141029160) and [webhooks github repository](https://github.com/bigassforce/webhooks)

Answer (score 5):

Webhook looks like you are talking about JIRA integration with salesforce.

Yes. I worked on this...

There are two part for this integration

1. Salesforce part.
2. Jira Part.

You need to create a rest service on salesforce end

https://forceadventure.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/creating-a-custom-rest-api-in-salesforce/

Also You need to create a site so that webservice will be available without login to org..

Once your rest service and your site is ready...

So Now if I want to access that rest service then I need to use url like

**https://site-name-here.force.com/services/apexrest/your rest service end point here.**

Next Jira webhook part....

You need to use above url in Webhook.. Add url and select events when post methods should called...

And just setup completed.. You will recevice all JSON data from JIRA to salesforce...

Good Luck..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of webhooks notifications but from my knowledge if these notifications can be delivered to a HTTP POST. With this approach of Custom API in salesforce you don't have to use any middleman.

If this the case you can develop a custom API using APEX REST and deliver the notifications to this API.

Here is the sample where you can start creating custom API using @RestResource.

[rest API for Querying on Account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88715/rest-api-for-querying-on-account/88726#88726)

Comment: my worry is, the way you have explained it is simple so anyone with the link to your APEX REST can post data to your org. How to prevent that from happening when the service that is posting the webhook to salesforce has no security measure Auth/OpenID in place ?